# Cut string model formula in R

Tags: r, character, r-model-formula

I am struggling cutting a character model formula after a specific value. This is the vector I am trying to cut:

```
bla
#[1] "pseudoy ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6 + (1 | clusterid)"

str(bla)
# chr "pseudoy ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6 + (1 | clusterid)"
```

The desired result should look like this:

```
bla2
[1] "pseudoy ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6"
```

This is what I have tried:

```
bla2 <- gsub("+ (1 | clusterid)", "", bla)
```

But unfortunately this is not working :(

I would appreciate any help. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You have a formula, rather than just an ordinary string. For formula, there is its own way:

```
f <- as.formula("pseudoy ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6 + (1 | clusterid)")
# pseudoy ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6 + (1 | clusterid)

g <- terms.formula(f)

modelterms <- attr(g, "term.labels")
#[1] "x1"            "x2"            "x3"            "x4"           
#[5] "x5"            "x6"            "1 | clusterid"

retain <- modelterms[!grepl("|", modelterms, fixed = TRUE)]
#[1] "x1" "x2" "x3" "x4" "x5" "x6"

reformulate(retain, f[[2]])
# pseudoy ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6
```

My answer is assuming that you want the solution flexible enough to drop off all model terms involving conditional specification `|`, without prior knowledge on the content of the formula or the order of term specification.

Answer (score 0):

We can try with `sub`.  The `+` is a metacharacter, so it needs to be escaped.  Here, we match one or more spaces (`\\s+`) followed by a `+` (`\\+`) followed by one or more space (`\\s+`) followed by a bracket (`\\(`) and other characters following it (`.*`).  Replace it with a blank (`""`)

```
sub("\\s+\\+\\s+\\(.*", "", bla)
#[1] "pseudoy ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the fixed= argument to gsub()

```
gsub(" + (1 | clusterid)", "", bla, fixed = T)
```

If fixed = TRUE, pattern is a string to be matched as is.

Comment: @ZheyuanLi Since OP mentioned that he/she wants to cut the vector after a specific value, so i gave this answer. Here you just need to mention that specific value

Answer (score 0):

With stringr:

```
library(stringr)
bla <- "pseudoy ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6 + (1 | clusterid)"
bla2 <- str_match(bla, "(.*) \\+ \\(1 | clusterid\\)")[2]
bla2
#[1] "pseudoy ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6"
```